# How to get absolute path to captured video file (CameraX/2)?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm recording now video with CameraX:

```
       val name =
            "Front_record-" + SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT)
                .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + FILENAME_EXT
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        }

        val mediaStoreOutput = MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(
            activity.contentResolver,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        ).setContentValues(contentValues)
            .setFileSizeLimit(6000000)
            .build()

        currentRecording = videoCapture.output
            .prepareRecording(activity, mediaStoreOutput)
            .apply { withAudioEnabled() }
            .start(mainThreadExecutor, captureListener)
```

It records and **saves** video on

> /storage/emulated/0/Movies/**.mp4

But I dont know can I use **static** route path to video file.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a uri to your saved video in the onVideoSaved method "of the onVideoSaved callback"as follows ;

```
    new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull VideoCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
            // here you get the URI of your saved video
            Uri uri = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
            }
    
    @Override
    public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error: "+ message ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            
}});
```